# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have some problem about retrofit2

How to fix Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT in retrofit2

I don't know to fix it

What's my wrong ?

my json is

```
{
    "result": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "10",
            "type_name": "pppppp"
        },
        {
            "id_mt": "11",
            "type_name": "aaaaaa"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my model class is

```
public class MessageFastModel {
    private boolean result;
    private String message;

    private List<DataBean> data;

    public boolean isResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
        private String id;
        private String type_name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getType_name() {
            return type_name;
        }

        public void setType_name(String type_name) {
            this.type_name = type_name;
        }
    }
}
```

My code is

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("api/message_type")
 Call<MessageFastModel> listMessageFast(@Field("token") String token);
```

and

```
Call<MessageFastModel> dddddCall = ooooo.listMessageFast(Preferences.getToken());
                        dddddCall.enqueue(new Callback<MessageFastModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<MessageFastModel> call, Response<MessageFastModel> response) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d("ddd", "onResponse: " + response.body().getData().size());
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<MessageFastModel> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e("ddd", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
```

but My error is

> E/ddd: onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected
>   BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 44 path $.data

what's problem ? thanks!

Comment: compare your MessageFastModel and response json both need to be same

Comment: please show your MessageFastModel class

Comment: @joao86 i editted a post please check for me

Comment: @ARR.s are you sure that the JSON you are returning is that? Because there it does not appear to be anything wrong with the code

Comment: Yes,the response if not like that he put .@joao86

Comment: @joao86 yes Myjson return this!

Answer (score 2):

```
  @GET("photos")
Call<Model> savePhoto();
```

And Call your retrofit method like this >>>

```
 Call<Model> call = apiService.savePhoto();

        call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, retrofit2.Response<Model> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                try {
                    Model model;
                   // Log.w("resedatasync", new Gson().toJson(response));
                    model= response.body();
```

And Create Your Model Class like this

```
public class Model{

@SerializedName("ArrayName")
 public List<DataBean > arraylist= new ArrayList<>();

@SerializedName("message")
private String message;

public class DataBean {

    @SerializedName("id")
     private String id;

    @SerializedName("typename")
     private String typename;

    @SerializedName("typename")
    public void settypename(String typename) {
        this.typename= typename;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: did you print the response ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have problem

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 44 path $.data

We must know that where need `JSONArray` .You have `List<DataBean> data` .So your data must use `JSONArray` .

And may be your problem at

```
Log.d("ddd", "onResponse: " + response.body().getData().size());
```

You can do like this .

```
System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

And show your message .

And try this class .

```
public class MessageFastModel {
    private boolean result;
    private String message;

    private DataBean data;

    public boolean isResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public DataBean getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(DataBean data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
        private String id;
        private String type_name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getType_name() {
            return type_name;
        }

        public void setType_name(String type_name) {
            this.type_name = type_name;
        }
    }
}
```

And remove `Log.d("ddd", "onResponse: " + response.body().getData().size());`

Comment: That's wrong, the API returns a JSONObject, containing "result", "message" and "data". Only the "data" field is a JSONArray. The error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT" confirms that.

Comment: You `JSON` root must be `[]` in your response .

Comment: And could you show `MessageFastModel` class in your code ?

Comment: @KeLiuyue i editted a post please check for me thank!

Comment: Could you add `System.out.println(response.body().string());` ?And show the message .

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the structure of JSON doesn't matches with the structure of your recipient model class. Also use `@Expose` and `@SerializedName("receivingJsonVariableName")` for each variable in the model class.