# retrofit Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get just string request but it's give error like this

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

And my API output is like this :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Video uploaded successfully!",
    "data": {
        "video_name": "674631516178278_abc2.mp4",
        "video_thumbnail": "674631516178278_thumb0017.jpg"
    }
}
```

Code for response :

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            try {
                if (response.body() != null)
                    Log.e("UploadResponse>>>", response.body());
                layoutUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                    thumb.delete();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                layoutUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                    thumb.delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that how are you trying to parse the response ?

Comment: Please post POJO also

Comment: The json is a JSONObject. You probably tried to parse it into JSONArray.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT retrofit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346823/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-retrofit2)

Comment: Create a class with following contents

boolean status;
String message;
VideoDetail data;

And call this class on the return type.

Comment: Then what to change to get response?

Comment: please post your pojo here.

Comment: instead of `String` use `ResponseBody` you'll get the success response

Comment: After adding class rather then string it gives error : timeout

Comment: @AMANSINGH work! thanks...

Comment: if you got the answer, then please upvote and accept my answer. Thank you

Comment: @NikhilSolanki use JsonElement instead of Responbody . it will help you to convert Object easily with less cost of efforts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response< ResponseBody > response) {
        try {
            if (response.body() != null)
                Log.e("UploadResponse>>>", response.body());
            layoutUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
                thumb.delete();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            layoutUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
                thumb.delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a good solution. Proper solution is to create model according to the server response and instead of response body use that model. It could be a case server responds with message video upload unsuccessful and for that case user must be notified about the error.

Comment: yeah, the proper solution is create a pojo class of that, but someone already answered but don't know what happend, he deleted so i suggested like this

Comment: I can see why @AMANSINGH wants to process as String, as it's relatively easy to process different response structures through json parsing. Although, a better practice would demand that you use a type converter to do this heavy lifting.

Comment: @H4SN It can be a proper solution to read a String from the response, not all use cases can be the same, you don't always need to create a POJO.  So it can be a good solution, we just don't know.

Answer (score 6):

.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
.addxxxx

Answer (score 4):

Error say's you want to get result in String body.
If you want to do this,
Just add  ScalarsConverterFactory.create() in your Retrofit.Builder.

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```

Use retrofit Implementation in app level build.gradle.

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'

Comment: Thank you so much. I just needed to add ScalarsConverterFactory

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. The answer provided by Dattatray Nande i.e. simply adding ScalarsConverterFactory.create() in Retrofit.Builder helped.

Additionally don't forget to add content-type as shown below to your interface

```
@Headers("Content-Type: text/html")
@GET("/apiMethod")
Call<String> YourAPIFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about the flow of execution , we just have to write the ScalarsConverterFactory first and then the GsonConverterFactory because ,if we write GsonConverterFactory first then it will check for an json object and gets a text so it will give an error .
Hope it helps.

```kotlin
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseurl)
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```